# "Timeout while getting a connection from pool." Hangfire.Postgres

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, timeout, hangfire

I'm new to Hangfire, so probably I'm messing up somewhere. I have the Hangfire configured like in: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire#installation

but instead of:

```
 config.UseSqlServerStorage("<connection string or its name>");
```

I have:

```
 config.UsePostgreSqlStorage("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=pwd;Database=Hangfire");
```

So I created an Hangfire Database in my DB.

And then, I'm building and running my project. It is ok. Creating all tables in Hangfire DB at my postgres. It is working great.

But then, when I'm trying:

```
   BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => HubService.SendPushNotificationToUsers(threadParticipants,  messageApi.SenderId, messageApi.SenderName, messageApi.ThreadId, messageApi.Content));
```

I'm receiving an exception with the InnerMessage:

```
  "Timeout while getting a connection from pool." postgres
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It seems like a know [issue](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/273)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to turn off Connection Pool via ConnectionString or String Builder.

Here is how we do it

```
        var sb = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
        sb.Pooling = false;
        app.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.UseActivator(new WindsorJobActivator(container.Kernel));
            config.UsePostgreSqlStorage(sb.ToString(), new PostgreSqlStorageOptions() { UseNativeDatabaseTransactions = true });
            config.UseServer();
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to reduce the amount of HangFire workers instead?
Maybe these are consuming your connection pool as Hangfire uses by default 20 workers * X connections each (don't remember how many but they are several) and that could be consuming your connection pool... therefore the connection timeout...

You can set how many workers you want to use in the hangfire initialization.
In this example you would use only 1 worker...

```
app.UseHangfire(config =>
{
    config.UseServer(1);
});
```